# I'm trying to figure out how to write a gd class that will display a string in any font type

Tags: php, gd

Here is the class I have so far:

```
<?php

class txt2img {
    var $image;
    var $headertype;
    var $forecolor;
    var $fontsize;
    var $fontangle;
    var $font;
    var $string;

    //font size
    function fontsize($fontsize) {
        return $this->fontsize;
    }

    //forecolor
    function forecolor($forecolor) {
        return this->imagecolorallocate($this->img(),$this->forecolor);
    }

    //image file
    function img($image) {
        return imagecreatefrompng($this->img);
    }

    function display($string,$font) {
        //display all errors
        ini_set("display_errors", "1");
        error_reporting(E_ALL);

        header('content-type: image/png');
        $fcolor = $this->forecolor();

        imagettftext($this->img(),$this->fontsize(),0,0,$this->forecolor(),$this->font,$this->string);

        imagejpg($this->img());
        imagedestroy($this->img());
    }
}

?>
```

Anyone have any idea? Either it's late or I don't know, for some reason I feel blank when writing this one.

I want to be able to write the attributes first like

```
$gd = new gd;
$gd->fontsize('12');
//..etc
```

then the actual output would be written like this

```
$gd->display('this is my string','myfont.ttf');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this line is not good

```
imagettftext($this->img(),$this->fontsize(),0,0,$this->forecolor(),$this->font,$this->string);
```

because you set nulls whit $this->fontsize() and etc.

it shuld be

```
imagettftext($this->imgage,$this->fontsize,0,0,$this->forecolor,$this->font,$this->string)
```

I this this helps :)

Comment: thanks but do you think it would be possible once i get this thing working? like say if i have a few tabs and for each tab run the function from the class and output a custom font string?

Comment: Yea, why not? Each tab is new session to web server so new copy of your 'stuff'. 
And if you want to have many img's you should init that class whit new name $one = new txt2img(); $two = new txt2img() it this way you get different objects.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get an IDE with SyntaxHighlighting
2. Learn PHP5 OOP Basics
3. Read the error messages

You have a wild mix of `$this->img`, `$this->image`, `$this->img()` and `$image` there ...